# Tag wiki edits don't seem to appear on a user's activity tab if they are not the latest revision

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

As the title says, I believe that tag wiki edits are not appearing on a user's activity tab unless they are a the latest revision of that wiki.

To test this go and find a tag wiki that has multiple revisions (eg, [this one](https://superuser.com/posts/183049/revisions)), then go and look at one of the activity tabs for one of the users who *isn't* the author of the most recent revision (same eg, [this one](https://superuser.com/users/36565/hello71?tab=activity)) and try to find the revision that have made on that tag wiki.

A good source for this is the "Tag Editor" badge, which you can find on people's activities often *without* the corresponding wiki edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually *none* of the tag wiki edits are appearing, this was due to a backend change a few weeks ago that wasn't accounted for in the revisions query in activity.

This will be fixed in a build later today.

Comment: Really, I managed to locate a number of users with visible edits, for example [slhck](http://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck?tab=activity) has [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uRK1y.png) ... ah wait, as I type this I think I've realised - tag wiki *creation* is visible, but not any subsequent edits?

Comment: @DMA57361 - yep, we added distinct PostTypeIds for wikis a while ago and this query wasn't updated to include them...but will be in the next build.